# Jquery upload file: get duration of video

Tags: jquery-ui, response, jquery-file-upload, duration

I use jquery upload file and console.log result :

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOsysEbbmMOSkZXb3NfdEFQQ2s/view?pli=1

I got info file upload in original Files :

```
var file = data.originalFiles[0]; 
var postSize = file.size;
var filename = file.name;
var lastModified = file.lastModifiedDate;
```

But cannot get :

```
var preview = file.preview;
```

How to get duration length of file from file.preview?

Comment: The link is not working, "permission denied".

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Upload Video File and Get Duration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081120/html5-upload-video-file-and-get-duration)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I updated image link again.